# Using set() for computed values correctly in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I'm having an issue with setting a computed property (which is an array). I have the following `computed` property in my Vue component:

```
posts: {
  get () {
    if ( this.type == 'businesses' || this.type == 'business' ) {
      return this.$store.getters.getAllBusinesses.map(_business => {
        return _business
      })
    } else if ( this.type == 'shops' || this.type == 'shop' ) {
      return this.$store.getters.getAllShops.map(_shop => {
        return _shop
      })
    } else if ( this.type == 'events' || this.type == 'event' ) {
      return this.$store.getters.getAllEvents.map(_event => {
        return _event
      })
    } else {
      return this.$store.getters.getAllBusinesses.map(_business => {
        return _business
      })
    }
  },
  set (posts) {
    console.log(posts)
    this.posts = posts // Doesn't work - this causes a maximum call stack error, recursively setting itself obviously.
    return posts // Doesn't work either - this.posts doesn't seem to be changing...
  }
},
```

The console.log(posts) is exactly what I want - a filtered array of posts, see the below console log output.

[image: console.log Output]

My question is simply this: **how do I go about updated the computed posts value?**

If it is useful, I am doing the following manipulation to the posts:

```
  let filteredPosts = []

  this.posts.filter(_post => {
    _post.category.forEach(category => {
      if ( this.categoryFilters.includes(category.slug) ) {
        filteredPosts.push(_post)
      }
    })
  })

  let uniqueFilteredPosts = [...new Set(filteredPosts)];

  this.posts = uniqueFilteredPosts
```

This is purely to filter them. What I am console.logging is absolutely correct to what I want. So this might be a red herring.

Any pro-Vue tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `computed posts value` there is no value to a computed propery. Given that your computed props data-source is the $store, do you want to update the $store ? Otherwise add those category filters to the getter - your "value" will update accordingly.

Comment: I would recommend making computed value out of the filtered posts, which reacts to user input and showing the filtered posts to the user, rather than trying to change the store value (which is what you wanted to do like @birdspider said).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a [computed setter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter), you normally assign to whatever values underlie the computed's `get` function. See the example at the link.

In your case, you examine `this.type` and return something from the store based on it. The setter should probably examine `this.type` and *set* something in the store based on it.

Comment: Hi @RoyJ, thanks for your answer. I have also tried this, and I get the maximum call stack error as described above...

Comment: If you are doing `this.posts = posts`, you are assigning to the computed inside the setter, which is wrong. If you are doing something else, I would need to see what you are doing.

Comment: I am setting `this.type` to which ever is needed for the `getter` - and this is still giving a maximum call stack error.

Comment: `set` should also not return anything.